# Can a single technology be used to observe light at any wavelength?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light

Radio waves are observed using induction in antenna.
Visible light is observed exploiting electronic transition in matter.

Is it possible to do the opposite?

If not why?

Comment: Have you looked at the antenna sizes/electron level differences that would be needed, respectively?

Comment: I would not discard than in the not too long future nano-materials (much more complex than today's) could be developed, so that they have multiple sets of layers, each responding to a different part of the spectrum.

Comment: Sufficiently high-energy gamma rays can destroy any insturment.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I have no idea about these unfortunately. I don't see why antena couldn't be used to observe visible-light, while I can somehow feel that longer wave do not have enough energy to stimulate electronic transition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Potentially black body absorption can convert all radiation into heat, which can then be detected.

Comment: Won't there be some sort of wavelength cutoff depeendent on the size of the blackbody abosorber?  And, alternately, wouldn't any matter be smashed into nothing by stream of 500 TeV photons?

Comment: Just make it as big as necessary and cool it towards absolute zero

Comment: it doesn't matter how much you cool it, because high-energy photons would clobber whatever material it was made of.  And the point is, for any size you choose, you can always pick a wavelength much longer than that size.

Comment: So? Being hit by a high energy particle and having its state changed is "observing it". And for longer wavelengths just provide enough supercooled mass until you run out of universe. The OP said nothing about practicality.

Comment: the ultra-long wavelengths won't get absorbed by the blackbody and therefore won't be detected.  The high energy gammas will destroy the detector, and at that point, detection stops (not to mention that it won't be able to distinguish a 100 TeV pulse from a 10000 TeV pulse)

Comment: The OP should have been more precise them. My detector is made out of all the mass of the universe cooled to about 0K and is a one-shot device.

Comment: Great.  Then your device immediately collapses to a black hole and loses its ability to transmit information outside of it.

Comment: Not if it is a rather large Dyson shell. However, I will allow 1kg of mass outside to record whatever result pops up

Comment: doesn't matter what it is.  There is a maximum mass an object can have, which is given by general relativity.

Comment: I could dispute this, but then in the spirit of my argument what's wrong with it collapsing to a BH? In the time it takes it can be a very good detector. The OP did not specify how long it has to exist

Comment: +1. I though a single device for very wide spectrum is of course impossible (or the so called "single" device practically consists of several). However this kind of device would really allow a very wide spectrum, while being very simple and robust.

Answer (score 0):

It is common sense to mix phenomenons electromagnetic radiation and radio waves. EM radiation is the result of electron acceleration. Then higher the acceleration then higher the photon's frequency. Different from this the frequency of radio waves is the modulation of electron acceleration made from the antenna generator. But at the end antenna emit photons too. So what you want to detect really are photons, in a chaotic way from any EM radiation or in modulated way from an antenna. And any photons one can detect with a [bolometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolometer).

The real add-on of radio waves is the fact that with the help of the modulation one can receive and separate informations from the all around existing EM radiation. The energy of radio waves in the point of the receiver can be tiny comparing to the EM radiation all around. That is the point why you need radio receivers for radio waves and you will be not happy with the bolometer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that much about this technology, but the [nantenna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nantenna) is a tiny antenna that in principle can detect visible light; however, current implementations are still restricted to the infrared spectrum. While nanotechnology lets you scale antennas down to the nanometer range so that you can detect visible light and even ultraviolet light, I don't see any way that the technology could scale down to atomic and subatomic length scales, so you can't use this approach to detect x-rays and $\gamma$-rays